# Win32 API: How to change color of part of text in edit control

Tags: winapi

I have an edit control. I want to change color of several words (like syntax highlighting). Is it possible?

Comment: A RichEdit control can do it, although I don't know how well they work as a single line control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You need a [Rich Edit Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605(v=vs.85).aspx). There are many examples online of addyng syntax highlighting to Rich Edit controls. Eg. [Faster rich edit syntax highlighting](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm).